# Unable to install custom ROM, missing options in recovery menu

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, nexus

> In recovery, perform a full factory reset, wipe cache, dalvik cache
>   and wipe data/factory reset. (source: https://www.naldotech.com/how-to-install-custom-roms-on-nexus-6p-with-custom-recovery/)

But in my Android Recovery I can only see following options:

- Apply update from ADB (or SD card)
- Wipe data/factory reset
- Wipe cache partition
- Mount /system
- View recovery logs
- Run graphics test

No such thing as full factory reset, wipe cache, dalvik cache. There is also no "install" option.

My Recovery screen says:

```
Android Recovery, 
google/angler/angler, 
8.1.0/OPM6. ...(long version), 
user/release-keys
```

Prior to that I have installed custom recovery (TWRP) from Play Store. Perhaps TWRP should be installed differently?

Comment: Twrp can't get installed from play store. You need to unlock bootloader and then enter to bootloader mode and install twrp through adb commands.

Comment: @RahulGopi when you are in fastboot mode, adb commands don't work. Only fastboot commands work. overdrive, as suggested above, you need to flash a compatible Twrp image in your device. You cannot flash a custom ROM using stock recovery (not permitted).

Comment: @Firelord Thanks. I forgot about fastboot during commenting. Only adb is remembering at that time.  some commands example: https://handsetgeek.com/adb-fastboot-commands.html

Comment: @overdriven this link may help you https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928